# “Where” condition based on yesterday in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I need to grab doc from collection bases on field `createdOn`   `yesterday` but it seems not to be working. Is there any better solution for this query?

```
 var startOfToday = new Date(); 
 startOfToday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
 var endOfToday = new Date(); 
 endOfToday.setHours(23,59,59,999);

       
  const snapshot = await 

firestore().collection(collectionName)
  .where('createdOn',CONDITIONS.GREATER_THAN_EQUALS,startOfToday)
  .where('createdOn', CONDITIONS.LESS_THAN_EQUALS, endOfToday)
  .get();
```

And its giving me the `result(doc)` from firestore which `createdOn` = today(current date).

Comment: So ```createdOn``` is between 23,59,59,999 and 0,0,0,0 ? If a document is created now it adds 0,0,0,0 to ```createdOn```? Is there a job in the background that increments this ```createdOn``` every millisecond (hence the 999)?

Comment: No, nothing any jobs, will be create  manually

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what does not work with the query.  We can't see the results of the query, and we can't see your data, so we don't know what exactly is wrong.  Keep in mind that Firestore timestamps are always represented in UTC, which might be different than the timezone configured on the machine running the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to obtain a list of documents from a previous day(yesterday), you can use the following snippet of code.

```
const today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
const yesterday = new Date(today);
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
//For debugging
//console.log("Today: ", today);
//console.log("Yesterday: ", yesterday);
citiesRef = db.collection('cities');
const snapshot = await citiesRef
   .where('createdOn', '>=', yesterday)
   .where('createdOn', '<', today)
   .get();

if (snapshot.empty) {
   console.log('No matching documents.');
   return;
 }  

 snapshot.forEach(doc => {
   console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
 });
```

For the code to work, this is the way I have inserted data into my firestore.

```
const citiesRef = db.collection('cities');
const today = new Date();
const yesterday = new Date(today);
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);

await citiesRef.doc('SF').set({
  name: 'San Francisco', state: 'CA', country: 'USA',
  capital: false, population: 860000, createdOn: today
});
await citiesRef.doc('LA').set({
  name: 'Los Angeles', state: 'CA', country: 'USA',
  capital: false, population: 3900000, createdOn: yesterday
});
await citiesRef.doc('DC').set({
  name: 'Washington, D.C.', state: null, country: 'USA',
  capital: true, population: 680000, createdOn: yesterday
});
await citiesRef.doc('TOK').set({
  name: 'Tokyo', state: null, country: 'Japan',
  capital: true, population: 9000000, createdOn: today
});
await citiesRef.doc('BJ').set({
  name: 'Beijing', state: null, country: 'China',
  capital: true, population: 21500000, createdOn: today
});
```

As per to the code you have shared I do not see where you are subtracting one from today's date.

I hope you find this useful.